# Multiple joins with ordered by count ignores where conditions

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I am trying to only get rows from video_index that belongs to a specific category from category_video_rel and order the result by COUNT of view count. This is the query I'm using:

> ```
>   SELECT
>         COUNT(DISTINCT view_count.id) AS count,
>         view_count.remove,
>         view_count.video_id,
>         video_index.id AS video_id,
>         video_index.active,
>         video_index.remove,
>         video_index.title AS title,
>         video_index.date_published AS date_published,
>         category_video_rel.active,
>         category_video_rel.remove,
>         category_video_rel.video_id AS cv_video_id,
>         category_video_rel.category_id AS category_id
>     FROM 
>         view_count JOIN video_index 
>             ON view_count.video_id = video_index.id,
>         category_video_rel JOIN video_index AS v
>             ON category_video_rel.video_id = v.id
>     WHERE
>         view_count.remove = '0' AND
>         video_index.active = '1' AND
>         video_index.remove = '0' AND
>         video_index.date_published <= '$current_time' AND
>         category_video_rel.category_id = '$category_id' AND
>         category_video_rel.active = '1' AND
>         category_video_rel.remove = '0'
>     GROUP BY
>         video_index.id
>     ORDER BY
>         count DESC
> ```

The problem is it outputs all the rows from video_index with a view count higher than 0 regardless of the category. Basically, it's ignoring "category_video_rel.category_id = '$category_id'" in the WHERE condition.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Start here: `echo $query;`

Comment: I just get "Resource id #8"

Comment: That would (or should) be `echo $result;` !!!

Comment: yes, thats what I got.

actually this is the code I'm using to see the results which works fine:
`code` $i=1;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $videos .= $i . '<br>Video ID: ' . $row['video_id'] . '<br>Title: ' . $row['title'] . '<br>Count: ' . $row['count'] . '<br>Category ID: ' . $row['category_id'] . '<br><br>';
  $i++;
 }
 echo $videos;
 exit();`code`

Comment: I'll try again: `echo [YOUR QUERY HERE];`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure that I understand. You want me to echo out the mysql query I posted in the question?

Comment: I think you need to add category_id to your group by clause?

Comment: Tried adding category id to group by, nothing changed

Comment: Yes. That way, we can see what MySQL sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FROM` clause is mixing old style joins and new style joins
Instead try:

```
FROM 
    view_count JOIN video_index 
        ON view_count.video_id = video_index.id
    JOIN category_video_rel 
        ON category_video_rel.video_id = video_index.id
```